# React Native firebase dynamic link, deep linking [Android]

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using dynamic link in React Native, I have all the steps required for IOS and android setup. (dynamic link opens the app on both platform) but when I have deep link attached to it, on Android app is opened but deep link parameters are not passed.

IOS works fine, deep link works correctly.

```
"react-native": "0.67.4",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "12.7.4",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "12.7.4",

device: Xiaomi mi 9,
browser: Xiaomi browser,

deeplink: https://sweeftdigital.page.link/transfer_tip?userId=3
```

#### deep link debug version

[image]

#### video

[Press to see video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62855343/194759711-90720b17-f623-4fe0-aba6-450d1c8b2926.mp4)

In this video there are two browser: Mi browser and chrome browser,

1. Mi browser: when pressing dynamic link, it opens app directly without passing parameters.
2. chrome: when pressing dynamic link, it asks to open either in browser or open app, when you choose and app it passes parameters and deep link works.

#### AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.tipapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

  <application android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:exported='true'
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://www.sweeftdigital.page.link/” -->
        <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="sweeftdigital.page.link" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "tipapp://” -->
        <data android:scheme="tipapp" />
      </intent-filter>

    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

#### deep link handling with react navigation

```
const config = {
      screens: {
         webView: {
            path: '/transfer_tip',
            parse: {
               userId: (userId: any) => userId,
            },
         },
         authLoading: '*',
      },
   };

   const linking = {
      prefixes: ['tipapp://', 'https://sweeftdigital.page.link'],
      config: config,
   };
   
    <NavigationContainer
         linking={linking}
      ...
```

Is there anything incorrect or is it firebase dynamic links normal behaviour?

Comment: Have you put SHA certificate fingerprints on your firebase android project? They are saying it will be needed for Dynamic Link.

Comment: Thanks , I am going to upload app on store and it will generate fingerprint automatically, I will update status in couple of days.